# Restore a MySQL Database from just the .idb files

Tags: server, mysql, backup

So more or less here is what happened. I went to reinstall MySQL and when I did my backup, I backed up the /var/lib/mysql folder entirely. When I managed to get MySQL reinstalled, I placed the old folders back in but the databases will not load in. Ive done some research online and almost all of the articles and answers say you will need the corresponding .frm files, however, for some reason, my databases do not have said .frm files. Is there a way to recover these databases with just the .idb files or anything in the /var/lib/mysql folder?

Comment: try to get a better online search method, you'll find that kind of thing: http://www.chriscalender.com/recovering-an-innodb-table-from-only-an-ibd-file/

Comment: **@cmak.fr** Please [see me in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and mention this question?  Please? Pretty please?  **0:-)  AnDwHaT5:** this question is more suited for our sister site [dba.se]  and already [has an answer there](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6268/how-to-recover-an-innodb-table-whose-files-were-moved-around)